# How to combine system proxy and chrome proxy?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, proxy

There are some addresses that should be proxied to localhost and the rest should use the system proxy settings.

By default browser using the system settings. But when I try customize any proxy settings with chrome.proxy api the browser starts to ignore the system proxy for all requests.

Is there any way to use custom proxy for several resource and the rest forward according the system proxy settings?

Answer (score 1):

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1351717

Guys from chromium forum give the answer, that blocking of system proxy settings when using chrome proxy api is by design...

So there is no proper way to combine system and chrome configs.